# Unpack, modify and re-pack files in an MSI?

Tags: file, windows-installer, updating

I'm trying to figure out the easiest and most secure way to Authenticode sign binaries in one of my projects.

The easiest way I can see to do this is to grab the result of compilation--a completed install package containing all my binaries--extract the assemblies from it, sign them, then repack these signed assemblies in the MSI which then gets signed.

Lots of information out there about unpacking files from an MSI, but nothing about re-packing them.  How can I do it?

Comment: Hi Will, did you find an answer to your question ? I'm also interested by a way to do this securely. I also saw your other similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026044/how-do-you-integrate-authenticode-into-your-build-process. Any pointers today ?

Comment: @Seb unfortunately not.  No automated solution at all for any of this.  I still hope for one, but currently I've had to do the release build-sign-build installer process manually.

Answer (score 2):

Editing my original response....

If you want to embed signing into your unattended build process, you can just use the MSBuild SignFile task, which wraps the authenticode signing APIs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164304.aspx

Alternatively just use a call to SignTool.exe.

You will need to install your Software Publishing certificate onto the machine using certmgr.exe or the certificates mmc snapin. Once it's installed into the local certificate store you just reference it using the SHA thumbprint, which you can find on the certificate properties or by just listing the cert in certmgr.exe.

We have to regularly update our certificates so we have additional steps in our build to re-import the certificate locally at the start of the build, and pull in the certificate hash. I would advise against storing the hash in source control in case you have to go back and build an old version - it should be part of your environmental configuration, e.g. an env var or something else that can be decoupled from your source code.

Also, don't forget to timestamp the signed files so that the validity of the signature can be guaranteed. I would also advise you to decouple signing from timestamping. Timestamping is a network operation that can occasionally go wrong, so it's useful to be able to discriminate between a signing failure and a timestamping failure, since a timestamping failure is only an issue for gold builds that might be released publicly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't state what your build system is, but the (overly simplified) flow my projects go through are as follows (I use nant tasks for pretty much everything, triggered from CruiseControl.net)

1. Grab everything from source control
2. Build clean project
3. Grab unsigned files
4. Using `signtool.exe` sign all relevant files (e.g. exe, dll, ocx)
5. Build MSI (with WiX)
6. Do some custom post-build tasks on the MSI
7. Digitally sign the MSI
8. (Depending on build parameters) Compress MSI with a bootstrapper
9. Sign the bootstrapper
10. Upload to a staging area
11. Email Dev+QA teams that build is ready for testing.

If it fails anywhere along the way, then just email the Dev team.

You should be able to do this with MSBuild, Nant, or a variety of other tools. It'll probably involve a little custom work in places, but the end result is a reliable build system that requires *zero* human interaction with the build (unless someone wants to 'force' a build, even that is just clicking a button on a webpage or something)

Comment: Seems like a week's worth of work to figure out how to set that all up.  TFS here, btw.  Any detailed tutorials?

Comment: Have never used TFS, but this build system has evolved over three years... we just started with the basics and automated more over time when there was a bit of downtime between releases.